# Will the app get published to the store automatically after the review passed?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

I've developed an Android and Apple app, but I haven't submitted them for review yet. We have planned a date to release to store. I know if we submit the app for review, it might take 3 to 4 days But will it available on the store after the review passed? can we postpone the availability to store a few more days later?

Comment: You are probably looking for managed publishing. This may help you in the right direction: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS you can choose to either make the app available right after it's been accepted, to wait until you manually release it, or to release automatically at a certain date.